# Firebase users in the flutter

Tags: android, firebase, flutter, dart, firebase-authentication

Can we retrieve all logged-in users uid with their particular data stored in documents in another app like I wanna built two apps one of them for admin side which can edit data another is for the user who can only see that data.

Comment: There is no API that you can call directly from the client. The common solution is to store data for each user in a database, and then query that. See https://stackoverflow.com/q/44959788, https://stackoverflow.com/q/14673708, https://stackoverflow.com/q/38168973, https://stackoverflow.com/q/56566791.

Comment: @mdhv_kothari did you check the answer?

Answer (score 0):

You can retrieve all user information, but you need to add the data either in realtime database or firestore depending on what you are using in the application.

Therefore, when a user is authenticated, you can add the data of that user to the database under node `users`, and then retrieve all  the data of the users later on.