# ionic, firebase: How to get ALL user emails from firebase authentication

Tags: javascript, firebase, ionic-framework, firebase-authentication, ionic4

i'm trying to get the user email of ALL the users that are in my firebase authentication store, i need this information so i can allow user to message one another within the system. im not very experienced with ionic so pardon me if it's a stupid question.
i do not need the logged in users email, i already have access to it but am having trouble accessing all of them.

login code, not sure if exactly needed.

```
// login.page.ts
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { FormGroup, FormBuilder, Validators, FormControl } from '@angular/forms';
import { NavController } from '@ionic/angular';
import { AuthenticationService } from '../services/authentication.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-login',
  templateUrl: './login.page.html',
  styleUrls: ['./login.page.scss'],
})
export class LoginPage implements OnInit {

  validations_form: FormGroup;
  errorMessage: string = '';

  constructor(

    private navCtrl: NavController,
    private authService: AuthenticationService,
    private formBuilder: FormBuilder

  ) { }

  ngOnInit() {

    this.validations_form = this.formBuilder.group({
      email: new FormControl('', Validators.compose([
        Validators.required,
        Validators.pattern('^[a-zA-Z0-9_.+-]+@[a-zA-Z0-9-]+.[a-zA-Z0-9-.]+$')
      ])),
      password: new FormControl('', Validators.compose([
        Validators.minLength(5),
        Validators.required
      ])),
    });
  }


  validation_messages = {
    'email': [
      { type: 'required', message: 'Email is required.' },
      { type: 'pattern', message: 'Please enter a valid email.' }
    ],
    'password': [
      { type: 'required', message: 'Password is required.' },
      { type: 'minlength', message: 'Password must be at least 5 characters long.' }
    ]
  };


  loginUser(value) {
    this.authService.loginUser(value)
      .then(res => {
        console.log(res);
        this.errorMessage = "";
        this.navCtrl.navigateForward('/welcome');
      }, err => {
        this.errorMessage = err.message;
      })
  }

  goToRegisterPage() {
    this.navCtrl.navigateForward('/register');
  }

}
```

register code

```
// register.page.ts
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { FormGroup, FormBuilder, Validators, FormControl } from '@angular/forms';
import { AuthenticationService } from '../services/authentication.service';
import { NavController } from '@ionic/angular';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-register',
  templateUrl: './register.page.html',
  styleUrls: ['./register.page.scss'],
})
export class RegisterPage implements OnInit {


  validations_form: FormGroup;
  errorMessage: string = '';
  successMessage: string = '';

  validation_messages = {
    'email': [
      { type: 'required', message: 'Email is required.' },
      { type: 'pattern', message: 'Enter a valid email.' }
    ],
    'password': [
      { type: 'required', message: 'Password is required.' },
      { type: 'minlength', message: 'Password must be at least 5 characters long.' }
    ]
  };

  constructor(
    private navCtrl: NavController,
    private authService: AuthenticationService,
    private formBuilder: FormBuilder
  ) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.validations_form = this.formBuilder.group({
      email: new FormControl('', Validators.compose([
        Validators.required,
        Validators.pattern('^[a-zA-Z0-9_.+-]+@[a-zA-Z0-9-]+.[a-zA-Z0-9-.]+$')
      ])),
      password: new FormControl('', Validators.compose([
        Validators.minLength(5),
        Validators.required
      ])),
    });
  }

  tryRegister(value) {
    this.authService.registerUser(value)
      .then(res => {
        console.log(res);
        this.errorMessage = "";
        this.successMessage = "Your account has been created. Please log in.";
      }, err => {
        console.log(err);
        this.errorMessage = err.message;
        this.successMessage = "";
      })
  }

  goLoginPage() {
    this.navCtrl.navigateForward('/login');
  }


}
```

what i'm trying to get would be something like

1. user clicks a list/options
2. user picks one email
3. types any message content he/she wants to share, i'll share a small snippet

```
<ion-select>
    <ion-select-option value="email1">email1</ion-select-option>
    <ion-select-option value="email2">email2</ion-select-option>
    <ion-select-option value="email3">email3</ion-select-option>
    <ion-select-option value="email4">email4/ion-select-option>
  </ion-select> //probably will use *ngFor to do this.
```

[authentication service screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GvhCB.jpg)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no way in the client-side Firebase Authentication SDK to get the email addresses of all users in the system, as that would be a potential security risk.

If your app needs this functionality, you'll have to build it yourself. The two most common options are:

1. Implement a custom server-side API that uses the Firebase Admin SDK, which has such functionality.
2. Store the necessary user data in a database, such as Firebase's Realtime Database or Cloud Firestore, and have the client access it there.

In both cases *your app* controls what data is exposed about your users, which addresses the security concern.

Also see:

- [Retrieving a list of users who have registered using Firebase Auth](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46939765/retrieving-a-list-of-users-who-have-registered-using-firebase-auth)
- [Get list of user email addresses with AngularFire](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44959788/get-list-of-user-email-addresses-with-angularfire)
- [How to fetch all registered authentication emails in firebase](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61004896/how-to-fetch-all-registered-authentication-emails-in-firebase)

Comment: thanks a lot, spent a long time looking for this and the only information i could find is getting the current users details, so is there a way that whenever a user logs in i store his email in my cloud firebase or would that not be the case too? i'm also concerned if that's possible if it would produce duplicate results and would require a lot of method calling perhaps.

Comment: What you're describing is the second option I mention above, which is the most common approach I see for this use-case. You can prevent duplicate results, for example by storing the users with their UID as their key. I recommend reading some of the (deeper) links I provided, as there's a lot of information on this already.